# Sequelize not working after the web being deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am currently deploying my web to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I use PostgreSQL and Sequelize, so for example I have several models look like this:

**In models/USER.js**

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../config/database')


const USER = db.define('USER', {
id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
},
name: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null
},
email: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null
},
password: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null
},
authen: {
    type: sequelize.JSONB,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null

}}, {
  tableName: 'USER',
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false
})

USER.sync().then(() => {
 console.log('table created')
}).catch((err) => {
 console.log(err)
})

module.exports = USER
```

Also, when I need to retrieve data from the database, I will do

**In routes/users.js**

```
 const USER = require('../models/USER')
 ....
 router.get('/', (req, res) => {

     USER.findAll().then((users) => {
         res.render('controlcenter', {
         layout: 'layoutB',
         users
    })
})})
```

Basically the above will get all the users from the database when I access the localhost:3000/users, and it works perfectly on the localhost.

However, after deploying the web to AWS, when I try to access /users page, the web just keeps loading then throws a 504 Gateway Timeout error.

I am pretty sure this is a Sequelize or PostgreSQL related issue as all the pages that don't involve getting into the database and fetching data all work fine.

Here is how I connected to DB, I used RDS

**In config/database.js**

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

 module.exports = new Sequelize('****', 'postgres', '****', {
 host: '****.****.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
 port: 5432,
 logging: console.log,
 maxConcurrentQueries: 100,
 dialect: 'postgres',
 dialectOptions: {
     ssl: {
         require: true,
         rejectUnauthorized: false
     }
 },
 pool: {
     maxConnections: 5,
     maxIdleTime: 30
 },
 language: 'en'})
```

**In app.js**

```
// Database Config
const db = require('./config/database')

// Test Connection
db.authenticate()
    .then(() => console.log('Database connect'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error' + err))
```

Anyone can help me solve this or offer me some hints about how should I tackle this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts usually imply firewalling problems.

Since you have been developing locally, I assume that you have an RDS instance independent of your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Have you added your Elastic Beanstalk security group to your RDS instance?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html

Comment: Yes, RDS instance is added to the environment. The instance is also connected to PostgreSQL, so when the web is running locally, I can access data from there.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing.
To resolve it,

1. Go to your database instance detail
2. Check at the connectivity and security tab. At Security section, there is link to your VPC security groups (for example, mine is "default (sg-0e654bfe73401b7b1)").Click the link.
3. At the security group detail page, open the Inbound rules tab, then click the button "Edit inbound rules".
4. Click button "Add rule" at left bottom of the table.
5. For the type, choose "MYSQL/Aurora". At source section, type your EC2 security groups name. There will be some suggestion when you type the name. Click the correct security group name once you found it.
   To find your EC2 groups name, you can go to your EC2 dashboard. In
   navigation pane, choose Instances. At the list of instances, click
   the instance ID of the instance. Scroll down, and find the security
   tab. Under the security tab, there will be information of the
   security group ID.
6. Click Save rules